# Формула поиска ячеек

Tags: google-spreadsheet, excel

Подскажите, какая формула позволит мне найти определенную ячейку, на любом листе в книге, в столбце, и скопировать данные, которые будут в соседней ячейке?
Например: у меня в столбце *A* есть куча наименований. Рядом столбец *В* с количеством продаж данного наименования. Нужно, чтобы формула скопировала ячейку в столбце *В*, которая соответствует наименованию в столбце *А*.

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо использовать формулы `VLOOKUP()` или `LOOKUP()`. Для горизонтального поиска с сортировкой используется `HLOOKUP()`.

```
+---+---------+------+
|   |    A    |  B   |
+---+---------+------+
| 1 | Аксинья |  670 |
| 2 | Захар   | 1117 |
| 3 | Юрий    |  666 |
+---+---------+------+
```

Чтобы найти `1117` для значения `Захар`:

```
=VLOOKUP("Захар";$A$1:$B$3;2;0)
```

, где `2` - номер колонки в вертикально-ориентированном диапазоне, `0` - не сортировать при поиске;

или

```
=LOOKUP("Захар";$A$1:$A$3;$B$1:$B$3)
```

Здесь вы можете найти подробное описание и примеры [Список функций Таблиц Google](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=ru)
Здесь вы можете найти мой пример [Формула поиска](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r5WkSZ-2mVezayFR79r_gbDEXFxQC6Js6lJ7w_G5oVE/edit?usp=sharing)

Основное отличие `LOOKUP()` от `VLOOKUP()` в том, что у второй существует возможность задать параметр сортировки при поиске. Иногда это существенно влияет на результат, например, когда в вашей Таблице есть повторяющиеся значения или нелатинские символы.

P.S. Не совсем верно говорить "формула скопировала ячейку". Формула в ячейке лишь "отображает результат". Для реального копирования необходимо использовать программные средства.

Comment: >>> 0 - не сортировать при поиске ||| - неточность.  Параметр указывает на то, что нужно искать точное соответствие искомому значению. Это возможно и в несортированных данных. Если нужетн поиск по неточному соответствию (параметр 1, ИСТИНА), то диапазон поиска должен быть отсортирован.